# Pretty permalinks returning "not found" on localhost and server

Tags: permalinks

I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible. I have a wp site I'm currently building that, if I configure permalinks to be pretty, all pages returns the 404 page. The weird thing is that that happens on my localhost server and my own online server, both of which host other wordpress "pretty permalinked" websites. What gives?

Comment: Is the .htaccess file writeable and set up correctly with the WordPress rewrite?

Comment: Jesus... I could swear it was but when I double checked it wasn't. Well... serves as a lesson: never EVER trust your own brain. EVER!

Comment: :) no problem, just how some days go!